# FineUploader - add uploaded files on page load

Tags: php, jquery, initialization, fine-uploader

I'm trying to let user edit files they uploaded before.

I created a script, that returns the same HTML as is generated when I upload file.

```
function add_fineuploader_images () {
    $post_id = $_POST['post_id'];
    $media = get_attached_media( 'image', $post_id);
    if ($media) {
    foreach ($media as $image) {
    ?>
        <li class="qq-file-id-0 qq-upload-success" qq-file-id="0" data-id="<?php echo $image->ID; ?>">
            <span class="qq-upload-spinner-selector qq-upload-spinner qq-hide"></span>
            <img class="qq-thumbnail-selector" qq-max-size="100" qq-server-scale="" src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image->ID, 'thumbnail' );?>">
            <span class="qq-edit-filename-icon-selector qq-edit-filename-icon"></span>
            <span class="qq-upload-file-selector qq-upload-file"><?php echo $image->post_title; ?></span>
            <input class="qq-edit-filename-selector qq-edit-filename" tabindex="0" type="text">
            <a class="qq-upload-cancel-selector qq-upload-cancel qq-hide" href="#">Cancel</a>
            <a class="qq-upload-retry-selector qq-upload-retry qq-hide" href="#">Retry</a>
            <a class="qq-upload-delete-selector qq-upload-delete" href="#">Delete</a>
            <a class="qq-upload-featured-selector qq-upload-set-featured" href="#">Set as featured</a>
            <span class="qq-upload-status-text-selector qq-upload-status-text"></span>
        </li>
    <?php
    }
}
exit();

}
```

And on page load I'm calling AJAX Post to load the images into page:

```
var post_id = $('#post_id').val();
    $.post(Ajax.ajaxurl, { action: 'add_fineuploader_images', post_id: post_id }, function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        $('.qq-upload-list').html(data);
    });
```

This created the same preview, as when the files are uploaded via FineUploader.

Now, I would need to let FineUploader know about these, so DELETE and other methods work.

I initialize FineUploader like this:

```
 $("#fine-uploader").fineUploader({
  request: {
        endpoint: Ajax.ajaxurl,
        params: {
            action: 'attach_files',
            post_id: $('#post_id').val()
        }
    },
  deleteFile: {
        enabled: true,
        endpoint: Ajax.ajaxurl,
        method: 'POST'
    }
});
```

How should I reinitialize FineUploader? Or, is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to display files in the upload list that have been uploaded in a previous session, just use the [Initial File List feature](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/features/session.html).  No need to reinvent the wheel here.  If you want to reset Fine Uploader, use the [`reset` API method](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html#reset).

I've noticed that you are asking a lot of questions that are covered in the documentation.  I encourage you to take a close look at the [existing documentation](http://docs.fineuploader.com) and [demos](http://fineuploader.com/demos), which, we hope, are fairly comprehensive.

Comment: Thanks, I'm of course always trying to find answer in documentation. The problem for me is, the documentation is quite difficult for me to understand - it would be really helpfull to add some real-world examples right into it.

Comment: Many of the feature pages have example code.  I'd start with the feature pages, as each feature page also includes relevant links to events, methods, and options.

Comment: Thanks for hint where to look. Anyway, I got the initial file list working, but I'm trying to do the same in onSessionRequestComplete callback as I'm doing in the onComplete callback: `var fileContainer = this.getItemByFileId(id), $child = $(fileContainer);
                $child.attr('data-id',response.attach_id);`, but this obviously doesn't work in the onSessionRequestComplete. How can that be fixed?

Comment: Anything returned by your server will be passed to your onSessionRequestComplete callback.  See the [documentation for this event](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/events.html#sessionRequestComplete) for more details.

Comment: I'm receiving the `attach_id` in my response fine, just don't know how to target the created preview `li`, to be able to add the `data-id` paramater to it... It seems that the callback is fired after all the files were added, not after every file...